# Springer llncs TOC not working

Tags: table-of-contents, lncs

I can't get the TOC to work. I remember it worked before, but there was something I did (unfortunately I can't remember what it was), and after that the TOC just stopped working.

Here is a part from my document:

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{titlepage}
    %Some stuff here
\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%more stuff here blablabla
\section{test}
\subsection{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Raaja I added some more "code" to the example.

Comment: Could you also add the error message that you encounter?

Comment: @Raaja I don't get an error. I cannot even find a warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class sets tocdepth to 0, so your example could never worked. You can change the depth:

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} %show more in the toc
\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{titlepage}
    %Some stuff here
\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%more stuff here blablabla
\section{test}
\subsection{test2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Danke!